# How can I disable websites from being able to open App Store on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

As the title says, how can I disable websites from being able to open App Store on iOS?

I was reading a news website and clicked a link that opened a new tab (an advertisement) which then went on to opening my App Store and going to an Apps download page.

How can I disable websites from being able to open App Store on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I use 1Blocker and Adamant content filters to block most JavaScript and trackers. That and careful decisions about what sites to visit have stopped this entirely from my iOS experience.

The ways that an advertiser can pay for placement means that some sites, you will never be able to get around this annoyance, but when it does happen, you can make note of that site abusing your time and at some point, you can stop visiting those sites where you are forced away from their content that you came to read in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

This post will be useful. You manage this using accessibility settings of your iOS. I tried with iOS 11.

https://facepage2.blogspot.in/2017/12/how-to-restrict-safari-from-launching.html?m=1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: ... so if the link ever does the answer doesn't become useless.